# Is it normal if i have more than 200 objectboxes declared in a project?

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox

Im having a project where the requirement is to manage 200++ models persisted in objectbox. I've proceed with the plan, but i find it uncertain whenever i run "flutter packages pub run build-runner build" and it tooks around 15 - 20 minutes to finish. Is this normal??

I've created 200++ models with complex attributes and declared as Box for each of them, I'm not sure is this too overwhelm?

I expect the "flutter packages pub run build-runner build" process takes less than 3 minutes to complete.

Comment: add your log / code here

Comment: This depends on many factors, e.g. the processor and disk speed. We have not done any performance testing on the generator (or have a project of this size). But if you can pin point a hotspot we welcome you to open an issue in the repo: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart
Edit: as a general recommendation, maybe split the model into smaller packages with their own database instead of having one huge one.

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox I saw the devs release a new version to track the generator's performance, are u one of the dev? I've upgrade to the latest version 1.7.1, can you trace the issue for me?

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible.